# How can I add parameters to a Play template without commas nor order?

Tags: scala, playframework

I'd like to know how to improve my own kind of template's helper. For instance, I made an `autocomplete.scala.html` that receives parameters in order to be dynamic, something like:

```
@autocomplete("elementLabel","data-url-where-its-going-to-get-JSON-data","anyother","etc","foo")
```

Then I can use `autocomplete` component in any page I want to.

But I'm wondering how to make it easier to use, for instance, Play's `inputText` helper has the option you can add parameters using " ' " + parametername and then -> (probably lambda?) so, how could i implement it, so, I could, for instance make something like:

```
@autocomplete("data-url",'someattribute->"value", '_anotherOneWithUnderscoreWhyBtw->"whyunderscore")
```

autocomplete.scala.html

```
@**
*   Componente para pesquisa textual e sele��o de registro de relacionamento 1 para N
*   
*   Example:
*
*   @autocomplete("example.nested.id", "Unidade", "/sistema/buscarExemplo", myForm.get().getUnidade.getId.toString, myForm.get().getUnidade.getLabel.toString) 
*@

@(fieldId: String, fieldTitle: String, dataUrl: String, initIdValue: String, initTitleValue: String)

    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12">
        <label for="@fieldId" class="control-label">@fieldTitle</label>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12">
        <span class="input-icon input-icon-right" style="width:100%">
            <input type="text" class="autocomplete-relation" 
            name="@fieldId" 
            data-url="@dataUrl" 
            data-id-status="@fieldTitle" 
            data-init-id-value="@initIdValue"
            data-init-nome-value="@initTitleValue"
            style="width:100%"
            />
            <i id="response_@fieldTitle" class="icon-search blue"></i>
        </span>
        </div>
    </div>
```

As soon as new requirements appear i must add one more parameter and then modify it at all pages i call it. I wanted to use that component like that original checkbox, from play, for instance:

```
@checkbox(myForm("myField"),'_label ->"MY_LABEL", 'class->"MYCLASS")

 OR

@checkbox(myForm("myField"),'class ->"MYCLASS",'_label->"MY_LABEL")

 or even

@checkbox(myForm("myField"),'class ->"MYCLASS",'_label->"MY_LABEL",'anotheattribute->"VALUE")
```

and so on. How could I do it so I wouldn't have to fill all of them and the order wouldn't matter?

Comment: Could you post some of the code for the `autocomplete` template, and show how the additional parameters would be used in it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use repeated `(String, String)` tuples as the last parameter:

```
@(fieldId: String, fieldTitle: String, data: (String, String) *)

<div class="form-group">
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12">
    <label for="@fieldId" class="control-label">@fieldTitle</label>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12">
    <span class="input-icon input-icon-right" style="width:100%">
        <input type="text" class="autocomplete-relation" 
        name="@fieldId" 
        data-id-status="@fieldTitle" 
        @data.map{ case (key, value) => 
            @{key}="@{value}"
        }
        style="width:100%"
        />
        <i id="response_@fieldTitle" class="icon-search blue"></i>
    </span>
    </div>
</div>
```

And you'd call it the way you're wanting:

```
@autocomplete("someId", "someTitle", "data-url" -> "google.com", "data-attr" -> "someValue")
```

You could also use a `Map[String, String]`.

```
@(fieldId: String, fieldTitle: String, data: Map[String, String])
```

The rest of the template would remain the same, but you'd pass it something like this:

```
Map[String, String](
    "data-url" -> "google.com",
    "data-field-something" -> "value"
)
```